# How to force view update in middle of code execution?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Every once in a while I have a situation where my code changes some variable binded to the view, or even change some attribute of a Dom element, but the view renders only when all the code is executed, when I usually I don't need the effect anymore, like for example an animation for an Ajax data load.

Is there a way or a command that forces the DOM or Angular to revalidate its bindings or simple refreshes the view?

Comment: changedetection ? https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly it looks like you need to run change detection manually.

`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` would trigger change detection for view and child components.

[ChangeDetection Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#!#detectChanges-anchor)